# jQuery: receive extraParameters from triggerHandler()

Tags: jquery, jquery-triggerhandler

```
   $('<span>test</span>')
    .change(function(e){console.log(e.data);})
    .triggerHandler('change',{foobar:1});
```

I'm doing it wrong or it's bugged?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The extra data is passed as argument to the handler:

```
$('<span>test</span>')
.change(function(e, data){console.log(data);})
.triggerHandler('change',{foobar:1});
```

The documentation also says that it has to be an array, though it works with one object too.